# Copying entities in Core Data

Tags: iphone, objective-c, core-data, ios

I have a couple of Core Data entities... Student and Exam.

Now, the Exams is initially just one object per exam - Maths Exam 3, English Exam 2 etc.

There is a relationship between Students and Exams in my data model (a student can have several exams). But initially, the Exams are just floating free, and not attached to any students.

How would I make a copy of one of the exams and attach it to a student?

If I do something like:

```
[student addExamsObject:examObject];
```

...then I think it simply references the original exam to the student, rather than making a copy.

I need a copy because the Exam has a boolean 'hasTaken', which is YES when the student has taken the exam. But if I set that now, it will make it seem like all the students with that exam have taken it.

Clarification: I would rather not restructure my model. The data is taken from a couple of xml files, one each for Students and Exams, which are parsed into the Core Data store. For instance, an Exam object might look like this:

```
name:Maths 5
class-id:12
year-id:4
student-id:0
```

..with a Student object looking like

```
name: Dave
class-id:12
year=id:4
student-id:222
```

Various rules are meant to guide which exams get attached to which students... for instance if all the Exam's ids are 0 then all students take the exam. If class-id and year-id match, and student-id is 0, then the Exam gets added to students with the same class and year. If the student-ids match, then just that student takes the Exam. etc etc.
I cannot change the way the xml is outputted from the server.

Another issue is that Exam has too-many relationship to a Question entity... in other words, the questions in the Exam. And I have to store answers to the questions that each student gives in an exam.

---

Edit: I wish people would try to answer my question rather than tell me to restructure my whole program. There are reasons why the data model has been structured like it is.

Edit2: Maybe I will have restructure....

Comment: But if you don't give those reasons, and are modelling something in an unusual manner, surely people will infer that it's an oversight/mistake on your part? Not unreasonable I think (of course I was one of those people, which makes me slightly biased!)

Comment: One reason is that the entities Student and Exam are parsed in from the web as two separate xml files. I have no control on how these xml files are structured.

Comment: I've added to my answer, although I'm afraid I still don't see copying entities as the way to go. :-)

Comment: @cannyboy -- Just because you receive data in a specific structure doesn't mean you have model it that way in Core Data. Core Data is not a dumb database system, it is an object-based modeling system. Your data model should reflect the logical relationships of the living data not the means by which the data enters the model.

Comment: Thanks, I realise that. However, much of app already revolved around those already set up structures. Requirements have changed towards the end of development. There were a couple of additional requirements (to record each student's exam answers, and to count how many exams each student has left to do). Without these additions, I could have got by with the old structures. But now I realise I have to restructure things quite a bit, and am implementing paul and ben's suggestions.

Comment: Even in a "dumb database system" there is no need for your final schema to be defined by the structure of the source data! Let us know how you get on.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Exam shouldn't have a `hasTaken` property.  Think about it in the real world.  An Exam would not know about who has taken it because many people could have taken it.  The instance of taking an exam, then, should be a first-class concept in your model.

Consider this:

[Exam has many TakenExams, TakenExams belongs to Student http://yuml.me/6627495d](http://yuml.me/6627495d)

Now the concept of taking an exam is a real object, you can then model assocation metadata as well, such as `dateTaken`, `score`, and so on.

Also remember that Core Data expects you to have all of your inverse associations set up as well.

Comment: +1 This is the way to go. Relationships themselves are data and deserve equal standing with attributes when designing the model. This isn't a  kludge, its how Core Data is supposed to work.

Answer (score 1):

You don't usually copy an entity.  (I'm not sure what happens if you call `copy` on an `NSManagedObject`... it's not explained in the documentation, as far as I know. Experts can correct me. )

Just create another entity, or write a method which does just that.

I think another way is to make many-to-many relationships between `Exam` and `Student`:

- create relationships in `Exam` called `studentsToTakeThisExam` and `studentsWhoTookThisExam`.
- create relationships in `Student` called `examsToTake` and `examsAlreadyTaken`.

and set up the inverse relationships accordingly.

Comment: Your second idea is a great idea. Unfortunately, I also have to record   the student's answers to the exam questions (within the Exam entity), so I guess I will have to create a new exam and fill it with data.

Answer (score 1):

You really don't want to copy an Exam in this situation. You'd end up with lots of identically named Exams which didn't have a relationship with each other, and then you'd be forced to group them together (if you wanted to) by their name.

I'd recommend a new entity (perhaps "`ExamSitting`"?) which represents a `Student` sitting an `Exam`. You could then a to-many from `Student` to `ExamSitting`, and a to-many from `Exam` to `ExamSitting`. This enables you to have as many attributes on the `ExamSitting` as you like then (`hasTaken`, `grade` and so on).

**Edit**

Okay, given your clarification, I have a point or two to add (although they may not be what you're looking for). I understand that you're loading from files with a particular structure, but that doesn't necessarily have to dictate **your** structure.

With the XML files laid out as you now describe, I would still use an `Exam` - `Student` - `ExamSitting` model. If I were to implement it, I'd load all the `Student`s, and then, for each record in the Exams file, I'd create one `Exam` object, and then a number of `ExamSitting` objects, one for each `Student` that fits the criteria defined in the record. As I mention above, this enables you to store more information about each event, such as `mark`, `takenDate` and so on.

If you're sure there's no requirement to be able to store additional information at this granularity, you could just create a to-many relationship `studentsTakingExam`. This could be populated as you load each exam record by querying the loaded `Student` entities.

Comment: Thanks, I will try your suggestion.. Ben seems to have the same idea. An issue is that I have to store answers to the Exams questions, but I guess I can hang a GivenAnswers entity off ExamSitting. Databases give me headaches.

Comment: It all depends how sophisticated/complicated/detailed you need your model to be. You could have `Question` entities belonging to an `Exam`, and `Answer` entities belonging to both an `ExamSitting` and a `Question`. The possibilities are endless!

Comment: judging by my limited progress, endlessness is a possibility too.

Answer (score 1):

I would not argue (as You requested) if your modeling is correct or not. The procedure to copy an entity is, in general, quite complex, owing to the fact that, besides attributes, you also need to deal with the entity's relationships and copy them. I can not post here a huge amount of source code showing how to accomplish this, however, I can point you to a book where this issue is described in detail, with all of the source code you need. The book is the one from Marcus Zarra, "Core Data Apple’s API for Persisting Data on Mac OS X" by "The Pragmatic Programmers".